# OpenCart: cant save custom module settings

Tags: php, opencart2.3

I have this trouble on admin part of my module. Im used chmod -R 777 for site contains folder, but method validate returns me permission_error

OpenCart version: 2.3.0.2

module code:

```
    <?php
class ControllerModulemymodul extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('module/mymodul'); //подключаем наш языковой файл

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');   //подключаем модель setting, он позволяет сохранять настройки модуля в БД

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) { //если мы нажали "Сохранить"  в панели, мы сохраняем текущие настройки
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('mymodul', $this->request->post);
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }

         // ваши переменные
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');     

        $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

        // если метод validate вернул warning, передадим его представлению
        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        // далее идет формирование массива breadcrumbs (хлебные крошки)
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/category', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );

        //ссылки для формы и кнопки "cancel"
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/mymodul', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        //переменная с статусом модуля
        if (isset($this->request->post['mymodul_status'])) {
            $data['mymodul_status'] = $this->request->post['mymodul_status'];
        } else {
            $data['mymodul_status'] = $this->config->get('mymodul_status');
        }

        //ссылки на контроллеры header,column_left,footer, иначе мы не сможем вывести заголовок, подвал и левое меню в файле представления
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        //в качестве файла представления модуля для панели администратора использовать файл mymodul.tpl
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/mymodul.tpl', $data));
    }

    //обязательный метод в контроллере, он запускается для проверки разрешено ли пользователю изменять настройки данного модуля
    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/category')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }
        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you which OpenCart version use? also, please mention all file code of your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module code is not compatible with OpenCart version 2.3.0.2. You will need to compare your code with other any default OpenCart module code.

Some structure changes has been in version 2.3.0.2 by OpenCart.

Try to replace following code in your module.

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMymodul extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/mymodul'); //подключаем наш языковой файл

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');   //подключаем модель setting, он позволяет сохранять настройки модуля в БД

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('mymodul', $this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true));
        }

         // ваши переменные
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');     

        $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

        // если метод validate вернул warning, передадим его представлению
        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        // далее идет формирование массива breadcrumbs (хлебные крошки)
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/mymodul', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
        );

        //ссылки для формы и кнопки "cancel"
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/mymodul', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);
        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true);

        //переменная с статусом модуля
        if (isset($this->request->post['mymodul_status'])) {
            $data['mymodul_status'] = $this->request->post['mymodul_status'];
        } else {
            $data['mymodul_status'] = $this->config->get('mymodul_status');
        }

        //ссылки на контроллеры header,column_left,footer, иначе мы не сможем вывести заголовок, подвал и левое меню в файле представления
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        //в качестве файла представления модуля для панели администратора использовать файл mymodul.tpl
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/mymodul', $data));
    }

    //обязательный метод в контроллере, он запускается для проверки разрешено ли пользователю изменять настройки данного модуля
    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/mymodul')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }
        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```